# Linux shell script throwing error when installing unison

Tags: linux, shell

Trying to set up instance of [Facebook CTF](https://github.com/facebookarchive/fbctf) on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04 and am running into the following error when doing the quick setup.

```
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child died with signal 13
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
curl: (23) Failed writing body (390 != 16384)
```

Traced the error to function in /extra/lib.sh where install_union is being called from /extra/provision.sh

```
function dl_pipe() {
  local __url=$1
  curl --retry 5 --retry-delay 15 -sSL "$__url"
}

function install_unison() {
  cd /
  dl_pipe "https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/unison/download/" | sudo tar Jx
}
```

The URL links to a tar.zst file that I am able to download directly but am unclear why the shell script cannot. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script *can* download it but assumes it is something that it isn't.

The `J` flag of (GNU) `tar` tries to decompress the file using [`xz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XZ_Utils) prior parsing it. But the file is actually [`zstd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zstandard) and not `xz` compressed. Hence `xz` doesn't recognize the format.

It looks like Arch Linux's packages have been switched to use `zstd` instead of `xz` some time ago: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Arch-Linux-Pacman-Zstd-Near

But the question is why you (or the script) want(s) to install an Arch Linux package on Ubuntu. There should be a package for [Unison for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unison). Try to just use that.

Or, if you (or the script) insist(s) using the Arch Linux package, try to install the [Ubuntu package for zstd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zstd) (or clone https://github.com/facebook/zstd and compile it yourself) and change the line in question to

```
dl_pipe "https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/unison/download/" | zstd -d | sudo tar x
```

Or change the URL in the script so that it points to a (possibly older) package that still uses `xz` compression.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the file format. Regarding the purpose of the Arch Linux package for unison, only had this piece for documentation. "If you are going to be modifying files outside of the Vagrant VM, you will need to synchronize the files using Unison (bi-directional file sync over SSH). Once Unison is installed, you can sync your local repo with the VM." Which the Unison for Ubuntu should serve that purpose as well.